# find the number of subarrays of an array with XOR sum

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, time-complexity

You are given the following array A, We need to calculate the total number of sub-arrays with XOR sum X were, The sub-array should satisfy the conditions (X+1) = (X^1). Here is my solution,

```
def getTotalXorOfSubarrayXors(arr, N):
    X = 0
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, N):
      for j in range(i, N):
        for k in range(i, j + 1):
          X = X ^ arr[k]
        if X+1 == X^1:
         count +=1
        X = 0
    return count

arr = [3, 5, 2, 4, 6]
N = len(A)
print(getTotalXorOfSubarrayXors(A, N))
```

But this solution has a time complexity of O(n^3) which exceeds my time limit for a large set of arrays. Is there is any way I can optimize this code to have less time complexity?

Comment: Yes you can do that in O(n^2) , You just need third nested loop, You can erase that .  `for(int i=0;i<n;i++){for(int j=i;j<n;j++){ res = res ^ arr[j] if (res+1==res^1){count++} }}  return count`

Comment: Is this online somewhere so we can test our solutions?

Comment: You talk about A and X, but there are no A and X in your code.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode A is the Array arr and X is the XOR sum. X should be calculated. Sorry I will edit it.

Comment: Shouldn't `X` be set to `0` right before the `k`-loop?

Comment: And what about my first question? Where is this from?

Comment: Do you understand what does condition `(X+1) = (X^1)` mean? What values of X do suit to it?

Comment: @MBo In boolean algebra X xor 1 = Not X .... right?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode yes. we need to set X = 0. I missed that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition `(X+1) = (X^1)` just means `X` must be even. So just count the even xors by using prefix-xor-counts. Takes O(n) time and O(1) space.

```
def getTotalXorOfSubarrayXors(A, _):
    X = 0
    counts = [1, 0]
    total = 0
    for a in A:
        X ^= a & 1
        total += counts[X]
        counts[X] += 1
    return total
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVLBboMwDL3zFT6tIDgkmiZNSBz6A@1hOyChgRgEmkITZMKkfj0LhEGQqk3LJbGfn/1sp7urixTPrx2OY4XyBpiLUl/81klUUFwkL1jvOCWroGbqXaq8jSWeq7fhM0fM79roM4m85iJvXe0K4OSFDugTQwRkfhVyEGq1KonAgYupVs1csjEMdt0wbmMGbXboFXygVoSpGkMKWkrSfKwAryD2KUQaTKkVb6T5EXXsBEYoMjWgMCF/jMA9BpA97rvXZkIDIEaMmvi7WeRTR8fQEpBG2vkEmyZD8qMlYxJvja2eCaa27pnkOFOJbBvay6JSS9cqlgW7BqPEC6CJKCHeHHPSES0T01qNo0MulHv42Xd4CP7xK3Yp9AdD@cXKX1M8Ynrj@A0) (with tests)

Answer (score 3):

Operation `X ^ 1` changes the last bit of a number. So `****1` becomes `****0` and vice versa.

So we can see that for odd values of `X` value of  `X ^ 1` is less than `X`, but for even `X`'s  value `X ^ 1` is larger by one than `X` - just what we need.

Now we can count subarrays with even xor-sum. Note that we remember how many odd and even xorsums we already have for subarrays starting from zero index:

```
def Xors(arr, N):
    oddcnt = 0
    evencnt = 0
    res = 0
    x = 0
    for p in arr:
        x ^= p
        if (x % 2):
            res += oddcnt
            oddcnt += 1
        else:
            evencnt += 1
            res += evencnt
    return res
```