# How to optimally find the number of subsets of an array satisfying the given condition?

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, data-structures, bit-manipulation

We are given an **array of positive integers** and we have to **count all the sub-arrays** which satisfies the given condition :
X ^ 1 == X + 1, where '**^**' is a XOR operation and **X** represents **XOR** of all the elements in that sub-array.

**Example :**

```
Say, A[n] = [1 2 2 4 5]
And we are given another array 
Queries[m] = [[1, 3], [2, 4]]
so for Queries[i] = [l, r] (l & r are array indices.)
and we have to count all the sub-arrays (for which X ^ 1 == X + 1) in subarray A[l:r] (both inclusive).

This operation we have to perform for each query and return solution for each query in result[] array.

So here, result[] = [6, 3].
```

**Explanation** :

```
result[0] = 6, as all 6 possible subarrays in range (2, 3) satisfies the condition,
similarly, result[1] = 3, as only subarray A[2:3], A[3:3] and A[2:3] satisfies the above condition
```

**Constraits** :

> **N** (size of array)  <= 2 x 10^5
> **M** (num of queries) <= 2 x 10^5

**Brute Force** solution resulted in **Time limit error**, because as per the constraints the solution time complexity should be < O(n^2).

> **How to Optimally solve this problem?**

Comment: Have you thought about how to optimize? Usually with multiple-query related problems the smarter solutions come from being able to solving the current query quickly, in less than O(largest possible query) time from something that is known beforehand. For example, if your problem was to calculate the subarray sums given a bunch of queries of left/right indices, you could solve each query in constant time by storing all prefix sums, then removing the prefix sum before the left point from the prefix sum up to the right end point. Can you adapt such an approach for this question?

Comment: Oops, as a correction, I meant to say that you should be able to solve the current query in less than O(single solution). For this problem, a single solution, without any lookup, would involve computing the subarray XOR in O(N) (optimally). So, you should consider how to optimize where all queries, after some precomputation, are done in less than O(N) time each.

Comment: Have you tried any search, at least for the last week? Is this problem from some contest or homework?

Comment: @MBo, yes, this problem was asked to me in a company's contest , I tried searching for that but couldn't find the solution, the contest is over now.
I tried solving this problem, but couldn't find the optimal way to solve it using also/DS.
Thus looking for help

Comment: @wLui155, i tried this problem using some lookup as prefix sum problem, but still not able to get the exact approach for it. we can store the XOR like prefix sums and get the XOR of a subarray A[l, r] in O(1) using formula = XOR(0, l-1) ^ XOR (0, r). But we need to find the number of subsets in range [l, r], which satisfies X ^ 1 == X ^ 1, means we have to find all subarrays for which XOR sum (X) is such that, it has last bit '0' in it's binary representation. But how to do that optimally instead of looping around the complete array everytime ?

Comment: [Very close problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69188142/find-the-number-of-subarrays-of-an-array-with-xor-sum?noredirect=1#comment122288584_69188142)

Comment: You're on the right track; you've defined the condition for subarrays correctly, but to put it in even simpler terms, you're counting even subarrays. Because you need to know the total number of subarrays that are even within a range, what if we also keep track of cumulative frequencies `frq[i] = # even subarrays in A[0:i] inclusive`, and use that in conjunction with the prefix sum `pre[i] = total XOR for A[0:i] inclusive`? Note we could also define `pre[i] = is A[0:i] inclusive even` for simplicity.

Comment: @wLui155, thanks. I understood the approach. So basically we can store the state ```(e, o)``` where ```e = number of even subarrays``` and ```o = number of odd subarrays``` at each index i, and if we encountered any number '1/0' which makes XOR sum ```A[0: i]``` as odd we can add 'o' in total otherwise we can add 'e' in total and then update the ```(e, o)``` for current state.

Comment: @wLui155, now we have both ```pre/frq``` array, how do we solve for number of subarrays for each query A[l: r] in least time?